# Aligning of doughnut charts to top in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

When the labels of the doughnut charts are not the same height, the charts get pushed slightly on the y-axis. It seems like the chart is aligned to the bottom of the canvas, and the canvas will fill the container. Is there a way to align the chart to the top of the canvas? Placing the labels on top, it seems like the chart is aligned to the top instead (but still has same issue, now the charts are just pushed down)

[image: Misaligned doughnut charts on y-axis]

Comment: What you should be able to do is using three different canvasses and aligning them using a flex box.